# How do I embed a Heroku webpage as a custom console component?

Tags: visualforce, service-cloud-console

Hi thanks in advance for the help.  I'm building something like a notification page that currently is hosted as a php app in heroku.  How do I embed it as a custom console component (I suppose canvas or visualforce)?

I am able to pop up a VF page so I know how to do that, but encapsulating the application from Heroku is where I'm stuck.

Thanks
BY

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to create a Canvas app that you host on Heroku. To do so, first follow the documentation on how to create a Canvas app in Salesforce (a google search should point you to the latest doc on setting up canvas). One important step to not miss in Canvas setup is to add Console as your location in the canvas settings.

Once you have your Canvas app, you will be able to add it to your Console as a custom console component (either a footer component or a sidebar component of a primary or subtab).